# disabling text selection is not working in IE using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6

I tried disabling text selection using JQuery. It's working fine in Firefox but not in IE. I have a text input field with an id, say 123. For this element the text filled in should not be allowed for selection. Can anyone provide me with sample code? I am using IE 6.

Comment: but you can still enter text ? please show us what you have working so far ... might help

Comment: Please post the code you are using to disable the input field...

Comment: i know id 123 is probably just an example, but it's not a valid id :P

Comment: I feel that it would take less effort to upgrade every computer using IE6 still than to build a website that works fully with IE6...just sayin'.

Comment: @jbabey: numeric-only IDs have had complete browser support for many years and are entirely valid according to the HTML 5 working draft spec.

Comment: if($.browser.mozilla) {
  $("#123").css('MozUserSelect','none');
} This is what i am using for disabling text selection in firefox.

Comment: @AndyE does IE6 support HTML5??

Comment: IE6 hardly even supports HTML 4...

Comment: My project has a requirement that it has to work in IE6 too. Any help??

Comment: @jbabey: nope but you missed the first part of my answer where I said browsers have supported numeric-only IDs for many years.  IE 6 and lower included.

Comment: @Dilip: you can actually do this without JavaScript in IE 6, Opera and browsers supporting the CSS3 `user-select` property.  See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: I don't have IE6, but this works for IE7 at least

```
   $("#123").bind( "selectstart", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 8):

Take a look one of IE's proprietary, cancellable events, [`onselectstart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
$("#123").bind("selectstart", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

> **Working example (requires IE 6-10): http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/Cp76b/**

Combine this handler with your current solution.  Note that some browsers can disable user selection via the CSS3 `user-select` property or the `unselectable` (IE, Opera only) attribute.  For example:

```html
<input type="text" id="123" unselectable="on">
```

```css
#123 { 
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

> **Working example updated: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/Cp76b/2**

This makes the JavaScript solution redundant in those browsers, but gives the advantage of disabling the selection for those users that have JS disabled.

Comment: Yep thanks. your answer was helpful. I tried it and its working fine now... J

Comment: I'm pretty certain `-o-user-select` doesn't exist. Opera uses IE's `unselectable` attribute. +1 anyway.

Comment: @TimDown: that's right. IE 10 doesn't currently support `-ms-user-select` either, unless it's in the Windows Developer Preview build. I figured it couldn't hurt to add them to the list, though.  I expect support for them will be added in the near future.

Comment: @AndyE: Don't count on it. `user-select` isn't in the current CSS 3 spec, and Opera and IE already have a working alternative (`unselectable`).

Comment: @TimDown: did they remove it from the spec?  It *is* in [the user interface module from 2000](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-userint-20000216), but it's not in any of the newer documents that superseded that one.  I wonder why.

Comment: @AndyE: I don't really know what happened to it. Possibly it was seen by the powers that be as behaviour rather than styling and therefore inappropriate for CSS, but that's just a guess.

Comment: `-ms-user-select` is included in more recent IE 10 builds, so I added it to your answer. Hope that's OK.