# CSS 3.0 user-select property replacement

Tags: css, properties, obsolete

I am using CSS 3.0 and it is complaining that the "user-select" property doesn't exist.  Does anyone know what the appropriate substitute or replacement is?

Comment: What do you mean "it is complaining?" Are you trying to validate CSS3 through the CSS validation service?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`user-select` is [back in the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-4/#propdef-user-select) for CSS Basic User Interface Module Level 4. It is supported by most modern browsers (according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)), either prefixed or unprefixed.

```css
#something {
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

---

`user-select` was defined as part of [User Interface for CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-userint-20000216#user-select), which was later superseded by [CSS3 Basic User Interface Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/).  However, the latter document does not include specification of `user-select`.  After searching recently, I was unable to find any discussion on why it might have been removed from the spec.

See also: my answer on [disabling text selection is not working in IE using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038010/disabling-text-selection-is-not-working-in-ie-using-jquery/8038212#8038212).

Comment: @Andy...interesting stuff.  However, I just tried "selectable" and the style sheet says it doesn't exist in CSS 3.0 either

Comment: @MikeTWebb: It's not a CSS property, so you have to apply it to elements in the HTML, e.g. `<div unselectable="on">Can't select me</div>`. Also, I made a minor mistake — it's actually `unselectable` :-)

Comment: @Andy.....this is weird....maybe I'm doing something wrong but when I use this code, it says "unslectable is not a valid attribute for div" <div class="disabled_text_area" unselectable="on" style="overflow: scroll; ">

Comment: @MikeTWebb: nope, you're not doing anything wrong.  In an ironic twist to the plot, `unselectable` is not defined by the HTML spec either, so using it will invalidate your HTML.

Comment: @Andy...hmmm.  OK, so do you know if there is a way to disallow the user from selecting text in a div or textarea?  There must be, one would think

Comment: @MikeTWebb: don't misunderstand, `unselectable` *will* work.  You just have to make the hard choice of ignoring the errors resulting from it when validating your HTML.  There are also JavaScript events, such as `onselect`, that you can bind to, but support for those is sketchy too.

Comment: Old post, but there is now -ms-user-select as of IE10.

Comment: old post, but now chrome does work just fine with 'user-select'

Comment: For anyone coming back in 2020, `user-select` works on Chrome, Firefox, and Edge (since Edge is using Blink).